# ServerName directive in apache2.conf?

Tags: apache2.4

If you have multiple VirtualHost enabled, why do you need to add a ServerName directive in apache2.conf if you already has it in 000-default.conf?

Comment: You don't. We will need more detail on your specific case if you insist that you do.

Comment: I ask this question because if I didn't add the ServerName in the apache2.conf it will say "AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
"